# Adding two decimal variables and assigning values in bash

Tags: bash, unix

we have been asked to parse a csv file and perform some operations based upon the data in the csv
I am trying to find the maximum of addition of two numbers which i get from the csv file
that is the last and second last numbers, which are decimals
Following is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
#this file was created on 09/03/2014
#Author = Shashank Pangam
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

maxTransport=0
while read year month hydro geo solar wind fuel1 biomassL biomassC totalRenew fuel2 biodieselT biomassT
do
   while [ $year -eq 2012 ]
   do
      currentTransport=$(echo "$biodieselT+$biomassT" | bc)
      echo $currentTransport
      if (( $(echo "$currentTransport > $maxTransport" | bc -l)));
      then
        $maxTransport = $currentTransport
        echo $maxTransport
      fi
   done
   echo -e "Maximum amount of energy consumed by the Transportation sector for year 2012 : $maxTransport"
done < $1
```

and the following is my csv file

```
2012,January,2.614,0.356,0.006,0.021,114.362,14.128,1.308,66.74,196.539,199.536,81.791,
2012,February,2.286,0.333,0.007,0.017,107.388,13.952,1.304,61.277,183.921,186.564,81.545,
2012,March,0.356,0.009,0.02,108.268,15.588,1.404,63.444,188.705,191.318,87.827,11.187,
2012,April,,0.344,0.012,0.019,103.627,14.229,1.381,60.683,179.919,181.993,86.339,11.518,
2012,May,,0.356,0.012,0.01,109.644,13.789,1.473,63.611,188.517,190.913,92.087,12.09,
2012,June,,0.344,0.013,0.013,108.116,13.012,1.434,61.056,183.618,185.65,89.673,12.461,
2012,July,,0.356,0.017,0.008,112.426,14.035,1.403,58.057,185.921,187.61,87.707,10.464,
2012,August,0.356,0.016,0.008,113.64,14.01,1.513,60.011,189.174,190.999,94.592,11.14,
2012,September,1.513,0.344,0.015,0.01,110.84,13.435,1.324,56.047,181.647,183.528,82.814,
2012,October,1.83,0.356,0.012,0.02,111.544,15.597,1.462,57.365,185.969,188.186,91.42,
2012,November,2.022,0.344,0.01,0.014,111.808,15.594,1.326,56.793,185.521,187.911,82.919,
2012,December,1.77,0.356,0.007,0.022,116.416,15.873,1.368,58.741,192.398,194.552,85.526,
2013,January,3.021,0.357,0.007,0.018,114.601,15.309,1.334,57.31,188.553,191.956,83.415,
2013,February,3.285,0.322,0.012,0.023,102.499,13.658,1.246,52.05,169.452,173.094,77.914,
2013,March,0.357,0.016,0.025,111.594,14.538,1.419,59.096,186.646,189.884,88.713,11.938,
2013,April,,0.345,0.018,0.03,103.602,14.446,1.437,59.057,178.542,181.342,89.867,12.184,
2013,May,,0.357,0.02,0.032,108.113,14.452,1.497,62.606,186.668,190.117,93.634,13.166,
2013,June,,0.345,0.021,0.028,109.162,14.597,1.47,61.563,186.792,189.994,91.894,14.501,
2013,July,,0.357,0.018,0.024,119.154,15.018,1.45,62.037,197.659,201.027,90.689,14.523,
2013,August,0.357,0.022,0.02,113.177,15.014,1.44,60.682,190.313,192.949,90.065,13.28,
2013,September,2.185,0.345,0.021,0.026,106.912,14.367,1.411,58.901,181.591,184.168,88.254,
2013,October,2.171,0.357,0.02,0.029,109.123,15.158,1.483,64.509,190.273,192.849,92.748
```

The following is the error i get

```
./calculator.sh: line 16: 0: command not found
0
268.109
```

I don't understand why echo $currentTransport returns 0 while in the comparison it works and assigns value to maxTransport but throws the error for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$maxTransport = $currentTransport` is wrong, should be `maxTransport=$currentTransport` (no space, no `$` on the variable being set). Otherwise, it will interpret that you are trying to perform the `maxTransport` command giving `=` and `$currentTransport` as parameters.

Comment: As an aside: the `while [ $year -eq 2012 ]` loop will run forever. It should be an `if` statement or, if the input file is sorted, part of the while statement above it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$maxTransport = $currentTransport
```

Try this:

```
maxTransport=$currentTransport
```

The `$` in front of a variable gives its contents. By removing the `$`, the actual variable location of `maxTransport` is used instead as the destination for the contents of `currentTransport`.

Comment: Phew! i am dumb! :( Thanks for the help

Comment: @Shashank No problem! That's why we're here :)